# Tapir - Method too large

Tags: scala, tapir

Im defining endpoints using tapir however i get the following compilation error.

> [info] Compiling 3 Scala sources to
>   /endpoints/target/scala-2.13/classes
>   ... [error] Error while emitting/endpoints/Session$ [error]
>   Method too large: endpoints/Session$. ()V [error]
>   one error found [error] (endpoints / Compile / compileIncremental)
>   Compilation failed [error] Total time: 26 s, completed 12-Mar-2020
>   15:29:54

```
 val manualReviewEndpoint: Endpoint[(SessionModel.AuthToken, SessionModel.ManualReview.ManualReviewRequest), ErrorsModel.FailureResponse, SessionModel.ManualReview.ManualReviewResponse, Nothing] = endpoint
    .tag("Sessions")
    .description("Triggers manual review for sessions within date range")
    .post
    .in(auth.bearer)
    .in("sessions" / "trigger-review")
    .in(jsonBody[SessionModel.ManualReview.ManualReviewRequest])
    .out(jsonBody[SessionModel.ManualReview.ManualReviewResponse])
    .errorOut(oneOf(
      statusMapping(StatusCode.BadRequest, jsonBody[ErrorsModel.FailureResponse400]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.Unauthorized, jsonBody[ErrorsModel.FailureResponse401]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.NotFound, jsonBody[ErrorsModel.FailureResponse404]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.UnprocessableEntity, jsonBody[ErrorsModel.FailureResponse422]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.FailedDependency, jsonBody[ErrorsModel.FailureResponse424]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.InternalServerError, jsonBody[ErrorsModel.FailureResponse500]),
    ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like because i had so many endpoints with many statusMappings that it was causing the constructor to become too large.

I fixed this issue by putting `manualReviewEndpoint` into its own object.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to large length of endpoint, for me it worked by changing endpoint from 'val' to 'def'
Which would look like `def manualReviewEndpoint`

Comment: If you don't want to use `def`, `lazy val` also works.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `val` to `def` or `lazy val` worked for me at first as per the other answers but there were some cases I end up with the same error regardless. I ended up creating a separate object with all the classes and subclasses. ex:
`

```
import sttp.tapir.Schema

object SessionModelSchemas {
  implicit lazy val sSubClass1: Schema[SubClass1] = Schema.derived
  implicit lazy val sSubClass1: Schema[SubClass2] = Schema.derived
  implicit lazy val sSubClass1: Schema[SubClassN] = Schema.derived

  implicit lazy val sSessionModel.ManualReview.ManualReviewResponse: Schema[SessionModel.ManualReview.ManualReviewResponse] = Schema.derived
}
```

Then where you define the endpoint remove this import (or similar)

```
import sttp.tapir.generic.auto._
```

And import your new object instead.

```
import SessionModelSchemas._
```

It was really tedious but simple to do. If you miss a class you'll get an error like:

```
magnolia: could not find Schema.Typeclass for type Option[SubClassN]
```

Just add it and try again. It's a bit of a maintenance pain but I wasn't able to find another way.

For more info: https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/schemas.html

Comment: This solved my issue! thank you so much for posting it anyways even when the original one was done on 2020!